# Do neutrinos absorb light?

Tags: particle-physics, electromagnetic-radiation, standard-model, neutrinos, particle-detectors

I have been reading about neutrinos lately. One thing that I found amazing about these, is that their detection is not so easy.

My question here is, do neutrinos absorb light?

Answer (score 2):

Since they are uncharged they cannot interact with photons. In the standard model photons can only couple to charged elementary particles or charged gauge bosons, e.g  charged leptons such as electrons, quarks such as up, down and charged gauge bosons such as W+. Since they cannot couple to photons, they cannot absorb light. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response.                                 What are the other particles with which neutrinos interact??

Comment: In the standard model, particles (as you might know them currently) such as electrons, quarks (which make up hadrons like protons and neutrons) don't interact with eachother, but rather interact by the exchange of something known as a "gauge boson". So when two positively charged particles interact by the electromagnetic force they exchange virtual photons, causing them to gain momentum in the opposite direction and repel eachother. Each fundamental force has a gauge boson which are exchange in interactions of this fundamental force.

Comment: Whether or not a particle can interact with the gauge boson of a fundamental force depends on the properties of the particle, e.g only charged particles can interact via the EM force, only particles with colour charge can interact by the strong nuclear force. Neutrinos have tiny mass so interact with gravity (very weakly), but gravity cannot be described by the SM which is another issue entirely. But essentially neutrinos interact with the gravitational force with other massive particles, we just cant model it with a gauge boson (yet).

Comment: However neutrinos can couple to other leptons by the weak force in the SM, since they can couple to weak force bosons, Z0 and W+/W-. Feynmann diagrams representing this have been attached:https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Konstantin-Kouzakov/publication/263280916/figure/fig1/AS:296418863534085@1447683172533/Elastic-neutrino-electron-scattering-due-to-the-weak-interaction-Exchange-by-the-W.png

Comment: Also heres a youtube video which will allow you to visualise standard model interactions (skip to around 10 mins in) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MmG2ah5Df4g&ab_channel=ScienceClicEnglish

Answer (score 2):

One reason why neutrinos are so hard to detect is that they have no electromagnetic charge so they don’t feel the electromagnetic force. This means that they don’t absorb light or interact with photons in any way.

There are other particles with no charge - the most common is the neutron. But the neutron feels the strong force. If it gets close enough to a nucleus it will interact with the other neutrons and protons in that nucleus via the strong force. The by-products of this interaction will probably include charged particles such as electrons or alpha particles, or indeed photons, and all of these we can detect quite easily.

Unlike the neutron, the neutrino does not feel the strong force. Apart from gravity (which is insignificant at the atomic scale) it can only interact with other particles via the [weak force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_interaction). As its name suggests, weak force interactions are very rare. So a neutrino hardly ever interacts with other particles, which makes it very hard to detect.

Comment: I think i have read earlier that neutron are made of quarks. Neutron Isn't elementary particle. But I wonder since neutron is made of two down quark and one up so why neutron still don’t have charge since quarks have?

Comment: @Istiak The down quarks each carry a negative charge which is half as large as the positive charge on the up quark. So the net charge of the neutron is zero.

Comment: The neutron also feels the electromagnetic force through its magnetic moment. When placed in a magnetic field it can change orientation by absorbing a photon.

Comment: So neutron feels electromagnetic force cause quarks aren’t chargeless but neutron is chargeless. Since quarks can feel electromagtic force so neutron also feels it.